# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null que no puedo solucionar

Tags: javascript, cookies

dispongo de un popup en mi web que se debe registrarse como coockie y de hecho lo hace. El problema es que le tengo añadido al final una variable if que debe detectar si el coockie no esta registrado y dejar el popup abierto y en caso contrario, cerrarlo. Pero en la ultima linea recibo elo fallo que aparece en el titulo. Esta es la linea que falla:

```
if (!getCookie('Popup')) {
  document.getElementById("pop-up").style.display = "block";
}
```

Os dejo a continuación el código completo:

```js
function accepted() {
    setCookie('Popup', true, 1);
    document.getElementById("pop-up").style.display = "none";
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

if (!getCookie('Popup')) {
    document.getElementById("pop-up").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
        .popup {
                padding: 4em;
                top: 0;
                position: fixed;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: white;
                z-index: 999;
            }

            .popup p, .popup span {
                color: black;
            }

            .popup .close {
                background-color: transparent;
                box-shadow: none;
                border: 3px solid black;
                border-color: black;
                padding: 10px 20px;
                left: 50%;
                font-size: 12px;
                line-height: 13px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                font-weight: 900;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .popup .close:hover {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: white;
                background-color: black ;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
```

```html
   <div id="pop-up" class="popup" >
            <p>testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest<p>
            <button id="accept-cookie" class="close" onclick="accepted()">close</button>
        </div>
```

Alguien sabria como ayudarme con este problema?,
gracias y un saludo

P.D: Este mismo codigo lo tengo implementado en otra web, y funciona perfectamente.

Comment: ¿Tienes el script al final de la página?

Comment: @YohangelRamos Si,  de hecho la web esta online, aunque el mensaje lo tengo oculto para que no se vea, el fallo se muestra igual. http://www.kreativcampus-muenster.de/

Comment: En esa url inspeccionando no encuentro ningún elemento con id="pop-up"

Comment: @YohangelRamos claro, por que no puedo dejar abierto una publicacion que no funciona de manera correcta. La voy a publicar con display:none, espera

Comment: Prueba así:
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            if (!getCookie('Popup')) {
                document.getElementById("pop-up").style.display = "block";
            }
        });

Comment: Funciono, muchas gracias, mira que no haberme dado cuenta del DOMContentLoaded. Bueno, a veces uno necesita otros ojos para encontar el fallo. Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: @YohangelRamos Puedes añadirla respuesta, asi la marco como correcta y el post queda cerrado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que se esta ejecutando el script antes de que se termine de renderizar el DOM (y por ende el div con id "pop-up" aun no existe).

Una manera de solucionarlo es con el "DOMContentLoaded", que se encarga de ejecutar todo el código javascript dentro de su función una vez renderizado el DOM.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () { 
   if (!getCookie('Popup')) { 
      document.getElementById("pop-up").style.display = "block"; 
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

¿Has probado a hacer esto? Mas que nada para asegurarnos de que eso es nulo:

```
if (!getCookie('Popup')) {
  var popUp = document.getElementById("pop-up");
  console.log(popUp);
  popUp.style.display = "block";
}
```

EDIT1: Creo que el problema podria estar cuando estableces la propiedad display de css a none en vez de usar display none prueba a usar el atributo hidden o sea prueba a dejar asi la condicion:

```
if (!getCookie('Popup')) {
  document.getElementById("pop-up").hidden = false;
  document.getElementById("pop-up").style.display = "block";
}
```

y la funcion accepted() dejarla asi:

```
function accepted() {
  setCookie('Popup', true, 1);
  document.getElementById("pop-up").hidden = true;
}
```

Comment: Lo he hecho, al final el fallo es el mismo